# Reference Request-Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying metric spaces for first time. We are asked to follow N. L. carothers. 
The problems are quite good but I am unable to verify my solutions.
I would like if someone can suggest me book for Metric Spaces which has Problems and solutions in detail. so that I can get confident with these topics.
Thank You

Answer (score 4):

Try

> [Topology of Metric Spaces by S. Kumaresan](https://dusolution.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/s-kumaresan-topology-of-metric-spaces-alpha-science-international-ltd-2005.pdf)

The author motivate the concept in a geometrical way and gives lot of problems with sufficient hints!

Added: Here's the advice of the author John M.Lee from his preface of the book "Introduction to smooth manifolds":

> I have deliberately not provided written solutions to any of the problems, either
>   in the back of the book or on the Internet. In my experience, if written solutions
>   to problems are available, even the most conscientious students find it very hard
>   to resist the temptation to look at the solutions as soon as they get stuck. But it is
>   exactly at that stage of being stuck that students learn most effectively, by struggling
>   to get unstuck and eventually finding a path through the thicket. Reading someone
>   else’s solution too early can give one a comforting, but ultimately misleading, sense
>   of understanding.
>
> *If you really feel you have run out of ideas, talk with an instructor,
>   a fellow student, or one of the online mathematical discussion communities such as math.stackexchange.com*.
>
> Even if someone else gives you a suggestion that turns out
>   to be the key to getting unstuck, you will still learn much more from absorbing the
>   suggestion and working out the details on your own than you would from reading
>   someone else’s polished proof.

Comment: But He hadn't supplied solutions in details